# Better way to embed external site into new tab page than iframe in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: ajax, django, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Django website that I also want to make available in the form of a Chrome Extension.

The extension will **replace your New Tab page** with the front page of my Django website. **While the page is loading, I want a "loading" message to be visible.**

My first attempt at writing the extension used Chrome's XHR example code to replace the contents of `<html>` with the AJAX-loaded Django page. But since my webpage's static files were reference as `/script.js`, they didn't resolve properly once that code was embedded into the New Tab page.

**My current solution:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>New Tab (External)</title>
  <style>
  div#loading {
    color: #cccccc;
    vertical-align: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 300%;
  }
  iframe{
    overflow:hidden;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="height:40%"></div>
  <div id="loading">Loading your Agenda...</div>
  <iframe src="http://localhost:8000" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Problems with my current solution:**

- The iframe has scroll bars
- Not sure how to make the loading message disappear once the iframe finishes loading

Is there a **better approach** to writing this Chrome Extension?
If not, how do I **work around these two problems**?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to just render a "loading" screen and do an actual redirect to your front page?

Comment: @lanzz Unfortunately, that interferes with some niceties of Chrome's new tab page -- the immediate redirect impedes those who try to start typing a new URL as soon as they open a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

You could inject the HTML in the new tab page's DOM as in your first attempt, and add a `<base href="http://your.site/frontpage/">` to the document's `<head>` tag in order to resolve the relative resource URLs in your page correctly. I've tested it and dynamic creation of a `<base>` tag affects relative links as expected.

Alternatively you can just add the `<base>` tag to your actual front page's HTML. It will still work when the page is loaded directly.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about `<base>` tags -- thanks for the suggestion! The CSS loads properly, but it seems that my actual front page's JS scripts aren't being executed (although Chrome Inspector doesn't complain). The Network tab in the Inspector suggests my Javascript files aren't loaded at all -- do you know if this a Chrome permissions error, or something else?

Comment: Please post your code for loading and injecting the page in the DOM.